# Best practice/performance between descendent and direct descendent selectors

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm wondering about the best practice and performance between using a descendent selector or a direct descendent selector. In the first case shown in the HTML below, both selectors would work equally because there is only one child.

```
<div>
    <p>Foo Bar</p>
</div>
```

In the markup above, is `div p` or `div > p` better practice/performance?

---

In the HTML below, there are several children elements.

```
<div>
    <p>
        <a>
            <span>Foo Bar</span
        </a>
    </p>
</div>
```

Assuming the desired target is the span tag, is `div span` or `div > p > a > span` better practice/performance?

Comment: For the last case, even just `span` could be the “best practice” … depends on what is needed to be achieved specifically. CSS rules are evaluated from right to left, so with `foo > bar` the browser can terminate the process of checking whether the rule applies for a given `bar` element as soon as the has looked at its parent element, whereas with the selector `foo bar` he has to go further up the DOM. The general rule of thumb is – be as specific as the current situation requires, but not _overly_ specific.

Comment: @BoltClock I am curious why you removed the `selectors` tag. Shouldn't that tag be marked as a synonym for `css-selectors` instead of keeping it but removing it from questions that use it?

Comment: @Keavon: The term is ambiguous; it can refer to CSS selectors, but it can also refer to Objective-C selectors, or "selecting mechanisms" in general (such as a dropdown control). So it can't really be marked as a synonym of anything :(

Comment: @BoltClock: [Tag description for `selectors`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectors/info) is specific (argh, there is that word _again_ …) to CSS selectors though.

Comment: Sounds like we should manually go through the tag's questions and fix the Objective C ones as `selector` and CSS ones to `css-selectors`. Should I post this on Meta?

Comment: @CBroe: Yes but there are too many questions with that tag that *aren't* about CSS selectors for me to merge or synonymize. Honestly I think the term is too ambiguous and should be avoided entirely when tagging questions. Keavon, I couldn't find any existing discussions so I'd say go ahead and post it.

Comment: Just noticed [selector] and [selectors] have completely different wikis even though they're basically singular/plural forms of the same word. See what I mean?

Comment: Meta question about changing the tags here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255461/we-need-to-sort-out-the-situation-with-the-selectors-tags

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't think about CSS performance. It's almost certainly a premature optimisation. If it's not premature now (i.e: not really a meaningful performance consideration), it will be in the near future (i.e: will be optimised well enough by browsers covering the vast majority of your target demographic).

The difference between `a b` and `a > b` is the <strike>level of "specificity"</strike> how deeply the selector engine must search to match `b` starting from `a`. While this might have an effect on performance (for large counts of elements matching `a b`), the `a > b` case might mean you'll lose flexibility in design.

In this case, if you attempted to 'optimise' performance by changing all cases of `a b` to `a > b`, you'd lose the ability to easily add more layers of DOM elements between `a` and `b` in your design without changing your CSS a lot. Leaving it less specific allows you to design in terms of 'behaviours'.

Also, while `a > b` (theoretically) does less work than `a b`, in most cases judicious use of classes on both levels will be equivalent (i.e: `a.x b.y`).

**edit:** Incorrect use of term `specificity` css-wise, and potentially incorrect algorithmicly. Better to state in terms of matching.

Comment: Just for precision’s sake – that is not actually a matter of “specificity” _as CSS defines the term_, `a b` and `a > b` are both selectors with the _same_ specificity `0,0,0,2`.

Comment: Curious, which term would be warranted in it's place?

Comment: Dunno, and I’m not criticizing – but since specificity has a special meaning defined in CSS, I just wanted to avoid possible confusion for other readers. Your explanation is of course totally correct in that they have different effects depending on actual DOM structure – but I can’t come up with a handy adjective to describe that spontaneously either :-)

Comment: And I also agree with you on not “overthinking” your selectors in terms of their “performance”. I know there’s some document out there from Google, where they explicitly advise to use only “simple” selectors, especially pointing to performance – but I think that’s just them being afraid their pretty Chrome might not look good in that regard if developers overdo it on their selector complexity :-)

Answer (score 0):

Answering strictly in terms of performance, I found [this reference](http://csswizardry.com/2011/09/writing-efficient-css-selectors/) that ranks child selectors as having better performance than descendent selectors.

> 1. ID, e.g. `#header`
> 2. Class, e.g. `.promo`
> 3. Type, e.g. `div`
> 4. Adjacent sibling, e.g. `h2 + p`
> 5. **Child, e.g. `li > ul`**
> 6. **Descendant, e.g. `ul a`**
> 7. Universal, i.e. `*`
> 8. Attribute, e.g. `[type="text"]`
> 9. Pseudo-classes/-elements, e.g. `a:hover`